# Nesting a div within a div isn't working

Tags: css, html

I'm in the process of teaching myself HTML again (the last time I did this stuff, people were still using tables) and running into some issues. I'm trying to figure out why the div known as "inset" is not showing up. Inside the pink box should be a black box but that isn't showing up. What's missing?

Below are the HTML file and CSS.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Wrapper -->
        <div id="wrapper">
            <!-- Project banner -->
            <div id="projectbanner"> <a href="#">Banner</a> 
            </div>
            <!-- Project data -->
            <div id="projectdata">Data</div>
            <!-- Summary section -->
            <div id="summary">Some stuff</div>
            <!-- Project body -->
            <div id="projectbody">
                <div id="inset">More stuff</div>
            </div>
            <!-- Footer -->
            <div id="footer">This is the Footer</div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Wrapper -->
    </body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
}
#wrapper { 
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1050px;
}

#projectbanner { 
 color: #333;
 background: #E7E7E7;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 width: 750px;
 height: 310px;
 float: left;
}

#projectdata { 
 color: #333;
 background: #888888;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 510px;
 float: right;
}

#summary { 
 color: #333;
 background: #666666;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 width: 750px;
 height: 200px;
 float: left;
}

#projectbody { 
 width: 1050px;
 color: #333;
 border: 0px solid #ccc;
 background: #F2BBE6;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 height: 850px;
}

#inset { 
 width: 800px;
 color: #fff;
 border: 0px solid #ccc;
 background: #000000;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 height: 350px;
}

#footer { 
 color: #333;
 width: 1050px;
 border: 0px solid #ccc;
 background: #BDBB8C;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Is this how the page should look? http://jsfiddle.net/a2EWC/

Answer (score 1):

You are floating the earlier elements in the page flow. When you float an element, it doesn't add height to its containing element, that's why the `#projectbody div` ends up behind the earlier `div`'s on the page. You can fix it by adding `clear: both` to the `#projectbody div`.

```
#projectbody { 
  width: 1050px;
  color: #333;
  border: 0px solid #ccc;
  background: #F2BBE6;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  height: 850px;
  clear: both;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a2EWC/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Take the projectbody div above the summery. float works near the element before it.

```
 <div id="projectbody">

     <div id="inset">

        More stuff

     </div>

 </div>

     <!-- Summary section -->

     <div id="summary">

             Some stuff

     </div>
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/shKcp/)